# How do I trigger a modal/pop up using an infowindow button in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, meteor, infowindow

I have a Google Maps InfoWindow. The content of the InfoWindow comes from a variable called `contentString` in my JS.

```
//content of InfoWindow
contentString = 
'<div class="alertPreview">
    <img class="alertPreviewImage" src="">
    <h3 class="alertPreviewTitle">' + 
        document.alertName + 
    '</h3> 
    <h6 class="alertPreviewLocation">' + 
        document.alertMunicipality + 
        '' + 
        document.alertProvince + 
    '</h6>
    <text class="alertPreviewContent">' + 
        document.alertDetails +
        '</br>
    </text>
    <button type="button" id="moreDetailsButton" class="btn btn-link alertDetailsButton">
        More Details 
     </button>
 </div>'
```

Note that the single quotes in the above code are ticks in JS.

I want to access the button in my `contentString` so that it triggers a modal/pop up. I was thinking of the following:

1. Somehow place a Meteor template in my `contentString` and then use template events for the button.
2. I can add an event listener. My button value is printed when I 
   `console.log($('#moreDetailsButton').html())` 
   but I can't use it for my event listener:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener($('#moreDetailsButton').html(), 'click', function(
       console.log('button clicked')
   })
   ```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried google.maps.event.addListener($('#moreDetailsButton') , 'click', function(
    console.log('button clicked')
})

Comment: Yes, I have. I get errors:

Comment: js?v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '__e3_' on string ' (…)ob @ js?v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:38vb @ js?v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:39_.A.addListener @ js?v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:96(anonymous function) @ map.js:71_.A.trigger @ js?v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:97JT.handleEvent @ marker.js:49(anonymous function) @ common.js:190_.k.Ce @ common.js:240_.k.kj @ common.js:239_.A.trigger @ js?

Comment: v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:97(anonymous function) @ common.js:138_.A.trigger @ js?v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:97_.k.yj @ common.js:212(anonymous function) @ js?v=3.exp&callback=GoogleMaps.initialize:38

Comment: If you are using jQuery anyway, you can use its own event facilities to add the listener. Why use the Google API? If the DOM node is not available when you are trying to attach the listener, you can try to hook to the infowindow's `domready` state, as described [here](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html).

Comment: You should be able to access the event from the template that contains your map in the normal meteor way: "click #moreDetailsButton": function(e,t){ console.log('hello')}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the event from the template that contains your map in the normal meteor way:

```
Template.map.events({
   "click #moreDetailsButton": function(e,t){ 
      console.log('hello');
   } 
})
```

You can use a template in you infowindow but I found that weird because the template isn't reactive as it is rendered when the infowindow is declared. I found that a simpler way to do this is to use plain modals instead of the provided infowindow. 
EDIT : In order to display the proper data that you can use the id of the marker (or whatever data is available when you instanciate your marker) and a session variable:

```
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
     Session.set('iwModalData', marker.id);
     $('#alertPreviewModal').modal('show');
  });
```

And then display proper content in your modal template from the session var information. If the only thing you'd want to display was the id of the marker :

```
Template.iwModalContent.helpers({
   "iwContent": function(){
      return Session.get('iwModalData');
   }
})
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, this did not work. :( I'm thinking it's because there is an error whenever I put the content of my contentString in a <template> tag. So the string does not have any template. The button cannot be called.

Comment: can you put the full code of what you are trying to do? instanciating the iw and all? Honestly gmaps IW are a bit fidly especially if you want reactive content in it. I'd advise using regular modals like I said (it's what I've ended up doing in the end).

Comment: Hi Mathieu. I've decided to use modals instead, like how you suggested. Now my problem now is: how do I hook a certain modal to a marker? 

I already have an html <template> for the modal.

I am calling that modal through my JS event listener:

 ` google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
          $('#alertPreviewModal').modal('show')
}) `

How do I let the modal know that it has to display the contents of the marker I clicked?

Comment: Hey zz, I edited my answer to give more precisions about that. Let me know if you manage to do it (and pls upvote comments and answers i want all the points XD )

Comment: Hi Mathieu,

I did this: 
`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {`
         `return Session.get('iwModalData')
`})`

in my JS.

From what I've read, I should be able to display that in my HTML by using this: `{{iwModalData}}`

Problem is, it's not working.

I have already done these too: 
`meteor add session` in my terminal
`import { Session } from  'meteor/session'` in the JS where I used `Session.set` and `Session.get`

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Already upvoted! Sorry for not upvoting in the first place. Please forgive the stackoverflow noob :)

Comment: You need to .set the value of the session var on click, and retrieve it in you IW modal template. Also I don't think you can access session vars from handlebars directly, you need to setup a helper. See the new edit. You can also update comments as well ;-)  (Stack noob here too don't worry)